# In Selenium, how do I access the name of the "Rendered Fonts"?

Tags: css, selenium, font-family

On the website I am trying to test, one of the fonts is not getting downloaded (it is blocked by the security) - and therefore, a substitute font is used.  In the screenshot below, "Montserrat" font was blocked from being downloaded; and therefore "Times New Roman" was used - also shown in the screenshot).

[image]

The selenium Java call `element.getCssValue("font-family")` returns Montserrat, because it is 'preferred/intended' font.  But in actuality the other font is used because Montserrat is not available.

I looking for help to see if there is a way to access the items in *Rendered Fonts* section.  If there is an entry, I plan to throw an error (i.e. I expect nothing to be listed in Rendered Fonts section)

Thanks :)